# Chess Game: Segmentation Fault Error. Can you find it?

Tags: c++, chess

Can you find my error? The program compiles, but when running it will crash and say segmentation fault: 11 after the fifth line. The program is in 3 files. I am making a chess game and right now all it is supposed to do is print the board. This is as far as it gets:

```
    cts/Software/Chess\ Game/a.out ; exit;
    setup complete
    rkb*qbkr
    pppppppp
    ________
    ________
    ________
    Segmentation fault: 11
    logout

    [Process completed]
```

File 1: board.h

```
    /*******************************
     *
     *   Matthew Buchanan
     *
     *   Bocan Projects
     *
     *   13:11 21 November 2014
     *
     *   board.h
     *
     *******************************/

    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    #include "piece.h"

    const int board_width = 8;
    const int board_height = 8;

    class board
    {
private:
    int square[board_height][board_width];
    piece *pieces[board_height][board_width];
    int make = 0;
    void print_square();
 public:
    void setup();
    void print();
    void update();
    };

   void board::print_square()
    {
cout << "_";
    }

    void board::setup()
    {
if(make == 1)                       //prevents setup function from being ran more than once
    return;
else
{
    for(int i = 0; i < board_height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < board_width; j++)
        {
            pieces[board_height][board_width] = NULL;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < board_width; i++)
    {
        pieces[6][i] = new piece(1, 1);
        pieces[1][i] = new piece(1, 2);
    }
    pieces[0][0] = new piece(2, 2);
    pieces[0][1] = new piece(3, 2);
    pieces[0][2] = new piece(4, 2);
    pieces[0][3] = new piece(5, 2);
    pieces[0][4] = new piece(6, 2);
    pieces[0][5] = new piece(4, 2);
    pieces[0][6] = new piece(3, 2);
    pieces[0][7] = new piece(2, 2);
    pieces[7][0] = new piece(2, 1);
    pieces[7][1] = new piece(3, 1);
    pieces[7][2] = new piece(4, 1);
    pieces[7][3] = new piece(6, 1);
    pieces[7][4] = new piece(5, 1);
    pieces[7][5] = new piece(4, 1);
    pieces[7][6] = new piece(3, 1);
    pieces[7][7] = new piece(2, 1);

}
make = 1;
    }

    void board::print()
    {
for(int i = 0; i < board_height; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < board_width; j++)
    {
        if(pieces[i][j] == NULL)
        {
            print_square();
        }
        else
        {
           pieces[i][j] -> print();
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
    }

    void board::update()
    {
return;
    }
```

File 2: piece.h

```
    /*******************************
     *
     *   Matthew Buchanan
     *
     *   Bocan Projects
     *
     *   13:11 21 November 2014
     *
     *   piece.h
     *
     *   Types:
     *   1 - Pawn
     *   2 - Rook
     *   3 - Knight
     *   4 - Bishop
     *   5 - King
     *   6 - Queen
     *
     *******************************/

    class piece
    {
private:
    int type;
    int team;
public:
    piece();
    piece(int, int);
    void set_type(int);
    void set_team(int);
    int get_type();
    int get_team();
    void print();
    //void move(); the location and the move functions will be kept by the board class in board.h
    };

    piece::piece()
    {
type = 0;               //0 is the null type
team = 0;               //0 is the null type
    }

    piece::piece(int t, int c)
    {
type = t;
team = c;
    }

    void piece::set_type(int t)
    {
type = t;
    }

    void piece::set_team(int c)
    {
team = c;
    }

    int piece::get_type()
    {
return type;
    }

    int piece::get_team()
    {
return team;
    }

    void piece::print()
    {
if(type == 1 && team == 1)
    cout << "P";
if(type == 1 && team == 2)
    cout << "p";
if(type == 2 && team == 1)
    cout << "R";
if(type == 2 && team == 2)
    cout << "r";
if(type == 3 && team == 1)
    cout << "K";
if(type == 3 && team == 2)
    cout << "k";
if(type == 4 && team == 1)
    cout << "B";
if(type == 4 && team == 2)
    cout << "b";
if(type == 5 && team == 1)
    cout << "^";
if(type == 5 && team == 2)
    cout << "*";
if(type == 6 && team == 1)
    cout << "Q";
if(type == 6 && team == 2)
    cout << "q";
    }
```

And File 3, which contains main: chess.cpp

```
    /*********************************
     *
     *   Matthew Buchanan
     *
     *   Bocan Projects
     *
     *   16:24 18 November 2014
     *
     *   Chess Game
     *
     *********************************/

    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    #include "board.h"

    int main()
    {   
board chess_game;
chess_game.setup();
cout << "setup complete" << endl;
chess_game.print();
cin.ignore();
return 0;

    }
```

Comment: And when you run it with a debugger, what line gives the error?

Comment: Why would I want to find your error? Is this a prize question?

Comment: As piece is not polymorphic and the size of the board is fixed, you should just use `pieces[board_height][board_width]`. Have a special piece type for an empty square.

Comment: This is definitely homework or project because it states Bocan Projects right on the code file. I don't think many people will be helping you on this one. I personally recommend(strongly suggest) actually trying to look for answers instead post code and questions at the first sign of trouble.

Comment: Bocan Projects is how I brand my personal projects, not homework.  I tried researching and debugging myself, but I truly had no idea what the problem was and the only thing I had to go off of was a segmentation fault message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this:

```
pieces[board_height][board_width] = NULL;
```

should be this:

```
pieces[i][j] = NULL;
```

Also next time compile it with -Wall. it should warn you that i and j are not used.